# Start and end of consecutive value run from given index

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I want to detect the first and last number in a vector equal to a certain value, within the same consecutive run of that value, without using loops.

In an example, let's assume I have the vector

```
x = [1 2 2 3 1 1 1 2 2 3]
```

I want to know the position of the first and last consecutive element starting from the 6th element.

So in this case it would mean to count how many consecutive 1s (before and after) there are from the 6th element of x. Expected output: `y=[5 7]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` twice, once working backwards from your reference index and once working forwards.

From your example:

```
x = [1 2 2 3 1 1 1 2 2 3];
idx = 6;

% Logical index for elements equal to x(idx)
same = (x == x(idx));

% Get last index (up to idx) where not equal to x(idx)
istart = find(~same(1:idx-1), 1, 'last')
% Get first index (after idx) where not equal to x(idx)
iend   = find(~same(idx+1:end), 1, 'first');

% Account for edge cases where consecutive run spans to the end of the array
% Could use NaN or anything else. These values will result in the value idx.
if isempty(istart); istart = idx-1; end;     
if isempty(iend); iend = 1; end;

y = [istart+1, idx+iend-1];
```

Output:

```
disp(y)
% >> y = [5 7]
```